# How to correctly work with non-primitive svelte stores?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, sapper, svelte-store

I don't understand how to use a writable store in a component and still have the DOM react to changes in the state.

I want to change the store state objects keys and retrieve its latest values which would then be used in a component.

The store does update correctly. The only issue is with updating the DOM on store state change.

### State and store types

```js
import { Writable, writable } from 'svelte/store';

export interface Words { [key: string]: boolean };

export interface SelectedWordsStore extends Writable<Words> {
  setWord: (key: string, state: boolean) => void;
  isWordSelected: (key: string) => boolean;
  reset: () => void;
}
```

### Store

```
function createSelectedWordsStore(): SelectedWordsStore {
  const state: Words = {};
  const store: Writable<Words> = writable(state);

  return {
    ...store,
    setWord: (key: string, isSelected: boolean) => store.update((words) => {
        words[key] = isSelected;
        return words;
    }),

    isWordSelected: (key: string) => {
      return state[key] ?? false;
    },

    reset: () => store.set({}),
  }
}

export const selectedWordsStore = createSelectedWordsStore();
```

### Usage

It's being used in a svelte component and in a TS helper file

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Word from './components/Word.svelte';
    import { words, getWordKey } from './helpers/words';
    import type { IndexProps } from './helpers/words';
    import { isBingo } from './helpers/bingo';
    import { selectedWordsStore } from './selected-words.store';

    const onWordClick = ({ currentTarget }: TypedMouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
        const parent = currentTarget.parentElement;
        const columnId = parent.dataset.columnId;
        const wordId = currentTarget.dataset.id;
        const key = getWordKey({ columnId, wordId })

        selectedWordsStore.setWord(
            key,
            !selectedWordsStore.isWordSelected(key),
        )

        isBingo(...); // <--- store used here as well
    }

    function isWordSelected(options: IndexProps): boolean {
        return selectedWordsStore.isWordSelected(getWordKey(options));
    }
</script>

<div class="container" data-testid="container">
    {#each words as wordGroup, columnId}
        <div data-column-id={columnId}>
            {#each wordGroup as word, wordId}

                <Word
                    on:click={onWordClick}
                    name={word}
                    isSelected={isWordSelected({ columnId, wordId })} <!-- USAGE -->
                    wordId={wordId}
                />

            {/each}
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

### Desired result

I want after calling `onWordClick` for the DOM to re-check `isWordSelected` and pass the latest boolean value to the `Word` component from the store

## UPDATE

I found a working solution by doing

```
isSelected={$selectedWordsStore && isWordSelected({ columnId, wordId })}
```

However, not sure this is the best way. Any suggestions?

## UPDATE 2

Now the reset callback on the store brakes the reactivity on the DOM. I.e. after pressing reset no state changes are reflected in the DOM or helpers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your original code does not work is that the line `isSelected={isWordSelected({ columnId, wordId })}` will be executed when the components render and only at that moment. meaning that any changes after render are not displayed.

Your proposed solution gets around that by having the store being a part of the equation as well, when the store changes, the entire `store && isSelected` part will re-execute.

In my opinion the best way to do this is to ditch all the extra complexity with the helper method and request the value directly from the store:

```
  isSelected={$selectedWordsStore[getWordsKey({ columnId, wordId })]}
```

This code will do the same thing as your code, except that it reads values *directly* from the store and because it refers the store directly it will update accordingly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. My goal was to abstract the store accessing so that none of the clients of the store know the implementation details. So, even though your solution works I'm not going to pick it. :)

Comment: in that case only your solution will work :)

Comment: Ah, noticed an interesting bug. If I call `store.reset()` the DOM stops responding to the store changes. Why would that happen?

Comment: @RolandJegorov if you want to abstract accessing of the store then you could use smart/dumb (presenter/container) component architecture, then only a few smart components will know of the store implementation details.

Comment: @WillTaylor sure, but that is beyond the point of this question. Still thanks for the suggestion. :) My biggest concern now is the bug of resetting the store.
https://github.com/Rolandisimo/bs-bingo/pull/1